# How to setup virtualmin to use cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, virtualmin

The goal is to have free ssl from cloudflare. So I moved dns records to cloudflare and is showing me - Certificate is Active. When I go to 'Analytics tab' it shows me traffic that is coming to the website. But when I enter the site https://www.zampadebattista.com I'm getting 'Your connection is not private'. It look that virtualmin is using his own self-signed certificate that I didn't setup. Do I need change something in virtualmin?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Everything seems to work well here ...

Comment: What do you mean? Is not working, when you open with https you  are getting -  Your connection is not private. It shouldn't be like that. https is not working

Comment: Not from here...

Comment: hmmm, I cleared All data from my chrome browser I also went to Incognito mode and I still have  - Your connection is not private. There is something more to clear? Can it be, that cloudflare is linking my IP with their catching server that has old data and is giving me this output? How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the same key and Certificate that is in the Directory is the same as the CloudFlare.

Clean Your Cookies ...
Enter the site with the Browser in Anonimo

Here it is working perfectly!

If you have solved, clarify the solution you found ...